# How to change the form fields by clicking the button in REACT.js?

Tags: reactjs, web-frontend

I have signup.jsx

```js
import React from "react"
import { render } from "react-dom"

import SignupContainer from "./containers/SignupContainer"

class Signup extends React.Component {
  user(){
   this.props.type='user';
  }
  hotel(){
   this.props.type='hotel';
  }
  render() {

    return (
  <div>
  Registration Type :
  <br></br>
  <button onClick={this.user}>user</button>
  <button onClick={this.hotel}>hotel</button>
  <SignupContainer type={this.props.type}/>  
     <h1>Signup</h1>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<Signup type='user'/>, document.getElementById('Signup'))
```

My SignupContainer.jsx

```js
import React from "react"

import Headline from "../components/Headline"

export default class SignupContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
  if(this.props.type=='user'){
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-12">
            <form action="/loginapp/" method="POST">
                
                
            First Name:
            <input type="text"  name="first_name">
            </input>

            <br></br>
            Last Name:
            <input type="text"  name="last_name"/>
            <br></br>
            Gender:  
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male
           <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /> Female
            <br></br>
                
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
          
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    } else if(this.props.type=='hotel'){
        return(<h1>{this.props.type}</h1>);
    }
  }
}
```

What i want is that when i click on user button then it should show me the registration form and when i click on hotel button it should print hotel without reloading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, `props` are passed down from parent to child, and should be considered immutable. On the other hand, `state` is used by components internally and can be updated with [`this.setState()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate), which triggers a re-render. Also, when using native JavaScript classes, you need to bind the class methods to the class if you want `this` to refer to class. So in your case, something like this should work:

```js
class Signup extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { // this is your default state
          type: 'user'
        }
      }

      user() {
        this.setState({
          type: 'user'
        })
      }

      hotel() {
        this.setState({
          type: 'hotel'
        })
      }

      render() {
        return ( < div >
          Registration Type:
          < br > < /br>
            <button onClick={this.user.bind(this)}>user</button >
            <button onClick = {this.hotel.bind(this)}>hotel</button>
            <SignupContainer type={this.state.type} />
            <h1> Signup </h1>
            </div>
        );
      }
    }

    render( < Signup type = 'user' / > , document.getElementById('Signup'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to change props of own component after component has mounted. Instead use states.

```js
import React from "react"
import {render} from "react-dom"

import SignupContainer from "./containers/SignupContainer"

class Signup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {type : this.props.type};
  }
  
  user() {
    this.setState({type: 'user'});
  }
  hotel() {
    this.setState({type: 'hotel'});
  }
  render() {

    return ( <div >
      Registration Type:
      <br /> 
      <button onClick={this.user}>user</button >
      <button onClick = {
        this.hotel
      } > hotel </button>
     <SignupContainer type={this.state.type}/ >
      <h1> Signup </h1>
         </div>
    );
  }
}

render( < Signup type = 'user' / > , document.getElementById('Signup'))
```

Comment: You should not modify state directly, but only using `setState()`. See the note here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

Comment: @bjudson is right as this thing just not render anything on the webpage

Comment: Oh yes, completely forgot the setState :P